# Attribute Fill Node - Shade Smooth - Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am using 3.0 Blender official release.

I am playing around with geometry nodes and trying to shade smooth the outcome of the geometry nodes.

From what I have seen, the way to go would be using an Attribute Fill Node and set the shade_smooth attribute to 1. Funny thing is that the official release of Blender 3.0 I am using seems to just have 3 attribute nodes:

- Attribute Statistic Node
- Capture Attribute Node
- Transfer Attribute Node

They are the only ones that show also in the Blender Documentation:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/index.html

However more attribute nodes exist in the documentation:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_fill.html

Have those additional nodes been discarded for the official release? Might they be included in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I can access those extra nodes and some others by enabling the Experimental Geometry Nodes Legacy from Blender General Settings.

I understand Geometry nodes is still a fairly new release so more time is needed to get a more definitive list of definitive nodes.

Comment: The way to go with the 3.0 nodes is to directly plug the geometry in the [Set Shade Smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/set_shade_smooth.html) node.